# what is wrong with my regex used in rename files in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file-rename, regexp-replace

target file name are like these:
specificLeaderString 2022-01-30.pdf
specificLeaderString 2022-02-28.pdf
specificLeaderString 2022-03-31.pdf
etc
the name I want is yyyyMMdd newSfx.pdf

- yyyyMMdd the date without hyphen

the script I used after cd into the directory in poweshell:

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '(\d[4])-(\d\d)-(\d\d}).pdf','[$1][$2][$3] smithChq.pdf'}
```

no change in file names in directory

I also tried

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d}).pdf','[$1][$2][$3] GGRbc.pdf'}
```

I expect all selected files with date suffix to be renamed with date without hyphen as lead and leaving out the original leading part out and insert " SmithChq" before the file suffix .pdf

btw I am using Windows 10 pro with all important update

Answer (score 0):

A simple Replace should do the trick. Unfortunatley I can not help you with fixing the RegExp, did not worked for me either.

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name.Replace("-","").Replace("."," SmithChq.")}
```

I Hope that helps!

Edit: Sorry, totally forgot about adding the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$leader = 'specificLeaderString'

gci *.pdf | where BaseName -match [Regex]::Escape($leader) |
  Rename-Item -NewName {
     '{0}{1}{2} newSfx.pdf' -f  [Regex]::Match($_.BaseName , '(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})').Groups.Value[1..3]
}
```

Or you could take advantage of the `[DateTime]` type:

```
gci *.pdf | where BaseName -match [Regex]::Escape($leader) |
  Rename-Item -NewName {
     '{0:yyyy}{0:MM}{0:dd} newSfx.pdf' -f  [DateTime][Regex]::Match($_.BaseName , '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}').Value
}
```

Comment: I tried both approach but I get similar error : Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'some leader string'.
At line:1 char:13
+ gci *.pdf | where BaseName -match [Regex]::Escape($leader) |
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: Did you define `$Leader` to contain your literal text that precedes the date? Are you piping actual `*FileInfo*` obejects that contain a `BaseName` property?  If you can append the relevant code to your quesiton, that would help...In the error message you copied, I have no idea where the "......"

Answer (score 0):

The best way of solving this issue is with the string replace method that user21534492 posted except if the rest of your string contains a dash.  Your code didn't work because the dash is a Regex special character and you need to use the hex value 0x2d.  The following code is tested

```
$filenames = @('specificLeaderString 2022-01-30.pdf', 'specificLeaderString 2022-02-28.pdf', 'specificLeaderString 2022-03-31.pdf')
$pattern = '\d{4}\x2d\d{2}\x2d\d{2}'
foreach($filename in $filenames)
{
Write-Host $filename
   $filename -match $pattern
   $date = $Matches[0]
   $dateNoDash = $date.Replace("-","")
   $newFilename = $filename -replace $date, $dateNoDash
   Write-Host $newFilename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Get-ChildItem` (alias `dir`) you can add parameters like `Filter` and `File` to help searching for files you are aiming to rename.

Because the filter cannot use regex, in this case I would advise to pipe the results through to a `Where-Object` clause to filter on filenames that end in what looks like the date pattern.

Then it is simply a question of piping to `Rename-Item`

```
$rootFolder = 'X:\Somewhere'
$newSuffix  = 'smithChq'
(Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter '*.pdf' -File) |      # first filter for files with .pdf extension
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$' } |   # next filter on files ending in yyyy-MM-dd
Rename-Item -NewName { '{0} {1}{2}' -f ($matches[1] -replace '-'), $newSuffix, $_.Extension }
```

<sup>The Get-ChildItem line is in between brackets in order to have that part finish to completion before piping the results through. Without that, it may pick up files that were already renamed (= waste of time)</sup>

P.S. your regex uses `\d[4]`, but the regex quantifier supported by .NET are curly braces, so that should be `\d{4}`